# How to choose separating symbol in citations?

Tags: citing, comma-separated-list, cite-package, multiple-citations, abntex2

Currently my citations are like:

---

"blah blah (1) blah blah blah (2-6) blah blah blah blah (7,8)"

---

But I need that "(7,8)" to be "(7-8)". I'm using abntex2cite package, which automatically made the citations that way. Note that with multiple citation (more than 2) it already is the way I need. The problem is with exactly 2 references.

I tried using

```
\usepackage[labelsep=endash]{abntex2cite}
```

but it didn't work (actually the error message says "Option clash for package abntex2cite").
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which bibliography style do you employ along with the `abntex2cite` citation management package?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that demonstrates the problem and generates the error you're getting.

Comment: Hi, Mico. Sorry for the delay. Actually I didn't choose any bibliography style. I tried a few (unsrt, dinat etc) but they were not acceptable according to my Univ. librarian. Not choosing any bibstyle somehow made the references acceptable, so I let it this way. Do you have a bibstyle sugestion that may help me getting double citations like (6-7) instead of (6,7)? The first standard I have to follow is that the references must be in order of appereance.